# Java - Circular shift using bitwise operations

Tags: java

I am wondering how to implement a ***circular*** right shift by k of the bitstring represented by the `int` bits.

```
public int rtCircShift(int bits, int k)
{
    return bits >> k;
}
```

All this code does is *return 0*, how can I make it a circular shift?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This should work:

```
 return (bits >>> k) | (bits << (Integer.SIZE - k));
```

Also see the [Wikipedia article on circular shifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift).

Comment: turned the logical `or` into a bitwise.

Comment: Still not correct, you need to use logical right shift, `>>>`.  Stick this in a method and you have `Integer.rotateRight`.

Comment: @rlibby: Thanks, fixed. @john: You should use the `rotateLeft`/`rotateRight` code from finnw`s answer. I'll leave this answer as it's the general way to do this, but it's much better to use a built-in function if there is one.

Comment: +1: You can do `return (bits >>> k) | (bits << -k);` This will work for `int` and `long` because the shift only takes the lowest 5-6 bits i.e. `64-k` is the same as `-k` (which for int is the same as `32-k`)

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to use Integer.SIZE rather than hard-coding 32? Also, why not Integer.rotateRight?

Comment: @Woody: Of course, finnw's answer is better in terms of using built-in functions, I just wanted to to show the DIY way. That's why finnw's answer has more votes, which is perfectly fine. My answer was what the OP wanted, finnw's answer is the clean way to do it (not reinventing the wheel)

Comment: @schnaader: Makes sense. I still suggest replacing 32 with Integer.SIZE.

Answer (score 47):

You mean you want the bits rotated off the right-hand side to appear on the left?

```
return Integer.rotateRight(bits, k);
```

Example:

```
int n = 0x55005500; // Binary 01010101000000000101010100000000
int k = 13;
System.err.printf("%08x%n", Integer.rotateRight(n, k));
```

output:

```
a802a802 // Binary 10101000000000101010100000000010
```

Answer (score 11):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5844096/4464702) by [schnaader](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34065/schnaader) is correct:

```
return (bits >>> k) | (bits << (32-k));
```

1. the first part `(bits >>> k)` right-shifts the value stored in `bits` by `k` bits and 'the third `>`' ensures that the leftmost bit is a zero instead of the sign of the `bits`
2. the second part `(bits << (32-k))` left-shifts the value in `bits` by `k`-complement number of bits

Now, you have two temporary variables where the first (32-k) bits are stored on the rightmost bits of var (1), and the last k bits are stored on the leftmost bits of var (2). The bitwise or operation simply ORs these two temp vars together (note the use of `>>>` instead of `>>`) and you have the circular shift.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
/**
 * Rotate v right with k steps
 */
public static int rro(int v, int k) {
    return (v >>> (k%32)) | (v << ((k%32)-32)
}

/**
 * Rotate v left with k steps
 */
public static int lro(int v, int k) {
    return (v << (k%32)) | (v >>> ((k%32)-32)
}
```

I think the other answers are wrong, since if you shift more than 32 positions, their algorithms fail. If you want bigger datatypes, you need to adjust the datatypes and the '32' in all places.

Comment: No, the other answers are right as the right operand (the number of positions to shift) is reduced to modulo 32. That is 5 <<35 is equivalent to 5 << 3.

Answer (score -1):

```
int x=12345,n=5;
System.out.println((x%10)*Math.pow(10, n-1)+(x/10));
```

To shift by one bit .

Comment: This is not a bit shift, but _digit_ shift (output is `51234`)

Comment: I liked that anyway