# Shifting a binary string circularly

Tags: java

I need to shift a binary string by 3 bits circularly. How can I implement this in java?

What exactly does "<<" operator mean?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844084/java-circular-shift-using-bitwise-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy. Remember that you cant perform rotation on String. Rather, what you can do it on numerics. Try:

```
    byte i = 15;
    byte j = (byte)(i << 3) ;
    byte k = (byte)(i >> 3);

    System.out.println("Here is result i=" + i + "and j = " + j + "and k = " + k);
```

This should give you i = 15, j = 120 and k = 1; That means it is non circular shift.

For circular shift, You can try:

```
    byte i = 15;
    byte j = (byte) ((i << 3) + (i >> 5));
    byte k = (byte) ((i >> 3) + (i << 5));
```

5 is like 8 -3 where 8 is number of bits your data type can have.

Answer (score 0):

For each element you need to construct the new value from two things:

1) value << 3

2) the value one below it (or the value at the top for the lowest value) >> sizeof(value) - 3

If you don't know how large your binary string is, I suggest you store all the 2)s (the 'leftovers') in a separate collection, then add them all in once you've done all the upwards bitshifting. Otherwise the logic gets too complex.

Comment: Btw, I have no idea what you are talking about