# convert int to bit array and do rotation operation on these bits

Tags: java, type-conversion, bit-manipulation

is there a way that i can convert int value to its bit representation and then rotate these bits and convert them back to int in JAVA , for example

considering each int is 4 bytes

```
17 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001
```

after rotation or circulation to the right by lets say 20 bits

```
0000 0000 0000 0001 0001 0000 0000 0000  = 69632
```

Comment: Cool. Do it, and if you have a question, post it here...

Comment: Why do you insist on converting to bit representation, vs just shifting the int? (Hint, use a long to capture the top bits.)

Comment: 10001 is 17 in binary...

Comment: @ppeterka i meant is there a way do it

Comment: `Integer.rotateRight(17,20)` See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5844084/995876

Comment: is it possible to rotate integer without affecting the sign bit of integer @Esailija

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the methods [`Integer.rotateLeft`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#rotateLeft%28int,%20int%29), [`Integer.rotateRight`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#rotateRight%28int,%20int%29), [`Integer.toBinaryString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29). All you need is already available in the Java API.

Comment: thanks, yeah it works as i wanted

Comment: is it possible to rotate integer without affecting the sign bit of integer @halex